# Undefined array key plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy creando mi primer plugin en wordpress para capturar datos en un formulario, este código lo fui colocando de acuerdo a unas instrucciones, al colocar ya el plugin en funcionamiento me sale esto y no se la razon

"Warning: Undefined array key "nombres" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Europea\wp-content\plugins\Formpets\formpets.php on line 66"

Aun así al enviarle info, ella se guarda en la base de datos.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Formpets
*/


// Cuando el plugin se active se crea la tabla para recoger los datos si no existe
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wpe_form_pets');
 
/**
 * Crea la tabla para recoger los datos del formulario
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpe_form_pets() 
{
    global $wpdb; // Este objeto global permite acceder a la base de datos de WP
    // Crea la tabla sólo si no existe
    // Utiliza el mismo prefijo del resto de tablas
    $wpe_pets = $wpdb->prefix . 'pets';
    // Utiliza el mismo tipo de orden de la base de datos
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    // Prepara la consulta
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $wpe_pets (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombres varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        celular varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        correo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        departamentos varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        ciudades varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        tipo_mascota varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        cantidad_mascotas varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        marca_comida varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        tipo_alimento varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        aceptacion smallint(4) NOT NULL,
        created_at datetime NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
    // La función dbDelta permite crear tablas de manera segura se
    // define en el archivo upgrade.php que se incluye a continuación
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta($query); // Lanza la consulta para crear la tabla de manera segura
}


// Define el shortcode y lo asocia a una función
add_shortcode('form_pets', 'Form_pets');
 
/** 
 * Define la función que ejecutará el shortcode
 * De momento sólo pinta un formulario que no hace nada
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function Form_pets() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style('css_clientes', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('js_clientes', plugins_url('app.js', __FILE__));
    // Esta función de PHP activa el almacenamiento en búfer de salida (output buffer)
    // Cuando termine el formulario lo imprime con la función ob_get_clean

    global $wpdb; // Este objeto global permite acceder a la base de datos de WP
    // Si viene del formulario  graba en la base de datos
    // Cuidado con el último igual de la condición del if que es doble
    if (
        $_POST['nombres'] != ''
        AND is_email($_POST['correo'])
        AND wp_verify_nonce($_POST['pets_nonce'], 'graba_pets')
        AND $_POST['celular'] != ''
        AND $_POST['departamentos'] != ''
        AND $_POST['ciudades'] != ''
        AND $_POST['tipo_mascota'] != ''
        AND $_POST['cantidad_mascotas'] != ''
        AND $_POST['marca_comida'] != ''
        AND $_POST['tipo_alimento'] != ''      
        AND $_POST['aceptacion'] == '1'
    ) {
        $wpe_pets = $wpdb->prefix . 'pets'; 
        $nombres = sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombres']);
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $celular = $_POST['celular'];
        $departamentos = $_POST['departamentos'];
        $ciudades = $_POST['ciudades'];
        $tipo_mascota = $_POST['tipo_mascota'];
        $cantidad_mascotas = $_POST['cantidad_mascotas'];
        $marca_comida = $_POST['marca_comida'];
        $tipo_alimento = $_POST['tipo_alimento'];
        $aceptacion = (int)$_POST['aceptacion'];
        $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $wpdb->insert(
            $wpe_pets,
            array(
                'nombres' => $nombres,
                'correo' => $correo,
                'celular' => $celular,
                'departamentos' => $departamentos,
                'ciudades' => $ciudades,
                'tipo_mascota' => $tipo_mascota,
                'cantidad_mascotas' => $cantidad_mascotas,
                'marca_comida' => $marca_comida,
                'tipo_alimento' => $tipo_alimento,
                'aceptacion' => $aceptacion,
                'created_at' => $created_at,
            )
        );
        echo "<p class='exito'><b>Tus datos han sido registrados</b>. Gracias 
            por tu interés. En breve contactaré contigo.<p>";
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" id="form_pets" class="cuestionario">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('graba_pets', 'pets_nonce'); ?>       
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="nombres" id="nombres" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Celular" name="celular" id="celular" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" name="correo" id="correo" required>
        </div>     
        <div class="form-input" style="display:flex;">
            <select name="departamentos" id="departamentos">
                <OPTION selected>Departamento</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="Amazonas">Amazonas</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="Antioquia">Antioquia</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="Arauca">Arauca</OPTION> 
                </select>
            <select name="ciudades" id="ciudades">
                <OPTION selected>Ciudad</OPTION>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <select name="tipo_mascota" id="tipo_mascota">
                <option selected>Tipo de Mascota</option>
                <option value="perro">Perro</option>
                <option value="gato">Gato</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Cuantas mascotas tiene" name="cantidad_mascotas" id="cantidad_mascotas" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Marca de alimento que consume tu mascota" name="marca_comida" id="marca_comida" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Con que tipo de alimentos tu mascota es magicamente feliz" name="tipo_alimento" id="tipo_alimento" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <label for="aceptacion">La información facilitada se tratará 
            con respeto y admiración.</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="aceptacion" name="aceptacion"
value="1" required> Entiendo y acepto las condiciones
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </div>
    </form>

</select>

    <?php
     
    // Devuelve el contenido del buffer de salida
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action("admin_menu", "Pets_menu");

function Pets_menu() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Formulario Mascotas', 'Mascotas', 'manage_options', 
        'pets_menu', 'pets_admin', 'dashicons-feedback', 75
    );
}

function pets_admin()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpe_pets = $wpdb->prefix . 'pets';
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Lista de Mascotas</h1>';
    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th width="">Nombres</th><th width="">Correo</th>
        <th>Celular</th><th>Departamento</th><th>Ciudad</th>
        <th>Tipo de Mascota</th><th>Cantidad de Mascotas</th><th>Marca de Comida</th><th>Tipo de Alimento</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody id="the-list">';
    $pets = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpe_pets");
    foreach ( $pets as $pet ) {
        $nombres = esc_textarea($pet->nombres);
        $correo = esc_textarea($pet->correo);
        $celular = $pet->celular;
        $departamentos = $pet->departamentos;
        $ciudades = $pet->ciudades;
        $tipo_mascota = $pet->tipo_mascota;
        $cantidad_mascotas = $pet->cantidad_mascotas;
        $marca_comida = $pet->marca_comida;
        $tipo_alimento = $pet->tipo_alimento;
        echo "<tr><td>$nombres</td>
            <td>$correo</td><td>$celular</td><td>$departamentos</td>
            <td>$ciudades</td><td>$tipo_mascota</td><td>$cantidad_mascotas</td>
            <td>$marca_comida</td><td>$tipo_alimento</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></div>';
    echo '<button style="margin-top:10px;"><a href="#">Descargar CSV</a></button>';
}

function addjQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'addjQuery');
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la parte específica de tu código en donde se presenta el problema? Es mucho código como para poder tomarlo y replicar el error

Comment: dentro de la función Form_pets donde se abre la condición $_POST['nombres'] != ''